# Can I store an uploaded file in a FileInputStream object?

Tags: java, html, servlets

the client supposed to to upload a .ppt file , and the server supposed to save it and display it.

I did stored the (request.getContent() )in a DatainputStream object.

```
    DataInputStream pptFile = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
```

But I cannot assign this type of variables ( DataInputStream) into an object from the library (org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow).

```
 DataInputStream pptFile = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
 SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow ( pptFile );
```

I need to use the pptFile as a FileInputStream variable, I know that I can convert from FileInputStream to DataInputStream easily, but How can I do the opposite? (Converting from DataInputStream to FileInputStream)

OR
At least Can I store the (request.getContent) inside a FileInputStream ??

Comment: Maybe the library requires to load the data from a file... So store it in a file and create a FileInputStream on it. ;)

Comment: According to the [documentation here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/SlideShow.html) all it needs is an `InputStream`, and a `DataInputStream` is an `InputStream`. Do you get an error trying to use the code above?

Comment: @ trutheality. yes, i get error if I assigned a DataInputStream object into the SlideShow object.

Comment: @Lujain What kind of error? A runtime error? Is there a stacktrace? Working with the InputStream directly is probably the right way to do this. The options for getting a FileInputStream are either to write to a file and then read from it, or to somehow get the file descriptor of the socket (if that's even possible).

Comment: I am sorry i just saw your comment.I cannot remember the error. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataInputStream` is not an appropriate class for your requirements (read its Javadoc more carefully).

You can store the request in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and then provide that to the `SlideShow` object. This might use up a lot of memory (PPT files can get many megabytes in size), but get that working first. Then, investigate using a temporary file to save the upload instead of keeping it in memory.